# Adding icons to simple_forms hints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I need to add custom html to hint and error elements that are generated by simple_form. Preferably I would like to customise it via config file. Generated html looks like this

```
span.error
  Some error message
```

Desirable output:

```
span.error
 span.icon.alert
 Some error message
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simple add background image (alert icon) for .error class?

or try to append wrapper in config:

```
config.wrappers :bootstrap, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
b.use :html5
b.use :placeholder
b.use :label
b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
  ba.use :input
  ba.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |input|
    input.wrapper :tag => 'span', :class => 'error-append' do |append|
      append.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
    end
  end
  ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
end
```

end

Comment: I'm using icomoon fonts as icons so setting background image is not really an option. I would also like to add links to hints etc ..

Comment: ok, can you provide code from config, which is generate this code?

Comment: its the standards config initializer generated by simple_form         `b.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :hint }  b.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :error }`

Comment: look above, maybe it helps (based on https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers)